# Java exception design : must be caught or declared to be thrown => Too much code impact

Tags: java, exception

Disclaimer : I'm coming from C# world so this is question might be biased by my previous experience

I have a method that is initializing logging. If this fails, the rest of the app should not run as any call to logger will throw a NullPointerException.

Today, my code is catching the exception and printing an error log via System.err. To me, this is a mistake, it should let the exception propagate up until it kills the app.

So I started removing the try catch and I suddenly got complains from the compiler saying that I should declare my exception on the whole stack where this method is called.

I understand the logic behind it and used to found it practical : you know how this method is capable of failing.

However, that doesn't sound right to me in term of separation of responsibility. I don't want the upper layers to be aware of this potential IOException fail, it is a very specialized behavior that shouldn't be known to , for example, the main method. 
And, if we push this logic, it means that :

1. the highest layer will eventually have to declare the whole scope of exceptions (From IO to Network to custom exceptions...)
2. Any addition of a new exception can potentially impact a lot of files and code

Am I missing something or this is intended exception design ?

Comment: Check into "Runtime exceptions", those that extend java.lang.RuntimeException. These are exceptions (such as NullPointerException) that do not have to be declared or caught.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is not a Java Exception, it is a Java Error.

> An Error is a subclass of Throwable that indicates serious problems that a reasonable application should not try to catch. Most such errors are abnormal conditions. The ThreadDeath error, though a "normal" condition, is also a subclass of Error because most applications should not try to catch it.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html

You can throw a error, which indicates that your app won't work anymore, which you declared as correct behaviour.

Comment: [IOError](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/io/IOError.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can encapsulate your checked exception in a RuntimeException (or one if its children), which does not force you to declare the exception:

```
public X execute() {
    try {
        return someThrowingMethod();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: In the OP case, might be better to throw an Error, as davidev states

Comment: It is indeed, through because he seems new to the Java world, he will most likely encounter the use of exceptions instead of errors. But you are right, Error should normally be preferred in the case he describes.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't initialize the logger and this is an enterprise application, I recommend killing your application with an exit code that explains the reason. If this is a client application, I recommend showing a message to the client stating the problem, recommending to the client that you report this back to you, and allowing them the choice of whether to proceed or not